# How to delete one specific Page of a ms-word document (docx) with POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm finding some ways to delete one specific page in my docx template, prefer to using POI. Is there any methods could do this?

I can get XWPFDocument object from my template file, but I don't know how to get specific "Page object", such like getPage(int pageIndex)?

```java
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(templateFile));
```

Comment: The page is not a valuable object in word processing. A word processing document body consists on a flow of body elements such as paragraphs, tables, fields, ... Those body elements are flowing over the pages. So what exactly is on a page is the result of this body element flow. I doubt that someone who not renders the word processing document is able predicting the exact start and end of a special page. `Apache poi` does not rendering the document. So I doubt `apache poi` is able predicting special page start and end.

Comment: Woo, this is convincing but a pity. I'll find other ways to solve it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm gonna change the template so that I can mark all specific content in XWPFTable objects. Then, to remove row might be a reluctant way.

Comment: Now I have already achieved my needs, but with little defect to leave some white vbcr at end of the dom (some cases if user wanna delete the last page).